# What formula is the equivalent of this function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi what formula is the equivalent of this code in excel?

```
int[]  workHours[300];
int function extraHours(){
   int extra=0;
   For(i=3,i<=300,i++){
      If(workHours[i]>8){
         extra += workHours[i]-8;
      }
   }
   return extra;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use this formula:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A300;">8")-COUNTIF(A1:A300;">8")*8
```

What does it mean?

First, the `SumIf()` takes the sum of all numbers, larger than 8.
Then, the `CountIf()` looks how many times this has been found, and for every one of those occurences 8 is subtracted.

Answer (score 2):

The most literal translation I can think of is

```
=SUM(IF(A3:A300>8,A3:A300-8))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A300>8)*(A3:A300-8))
```

entered as a normal formula.

Answer (score 1):

How does your Excel sheet look like? I will assume that the numbers of `workHours` will be given in column `A` of your Excel sheet.

Are you free to add additional columns? In Excel, just for simplicity, you do not need to solve every problem with a single formula. E.g., add an additional column `WorkHoursMinus8` in column `B` with `B[i]=A[i]-8`. Now, you can simply use the formula `sumif` to calculate the sum of all *positive* cells in column `B`: `SUMIF(B:B,">0")`.

Does that help, or do you really need to have a single formula without additional columns?

Comment: Thanks but I can't add another column and this is the problem